# How to call method without go to ConversationHandler in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

How can I fix this problem? I get information from the user, for example, email address, but if that address is wrong, I show an error message to the user, and I want the user to redirect to get the input email address again and show to the user please enter the email address again, or in this code, I want to rerun gender method after user enter wrong enter email address but how can I call gender method from email method?
The output is user should type something that ConversationHandler trigger and run the gender method to get the email address again

```
import re
 
from telegram import __version__ as TG_VER
 
try:
    from telegram import __version_info__
except ImportError:
    __version_info__ = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
 
if __version_info__ < (20, 0, 0, "alpha", 1):
    raise RuntimeError(
        f"This example is not compatible with your current PTB version {TG_VER}. To view the "
        f"{TG_VER} version of this example, "
        f"visit https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v{TG_VER}/examples.html"
    )
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, Update
from telegram.ext import (
    Application,
    CommandHandler,
    ContextTypes,
    ConversationHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    filters,
)
 
GENDER, EMAIL = range(2)
 
async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    reply_keyboard = [["Boy", "Girl", "Other"]]
    await update.message.reply_text(
        "Hi! My name is Professor Bot. I will hold a conversation with you. "
        "Are you a boy or a girl?",
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
            reply_keyboard, one_time_keyboard=True, input_field_placeholder="Boy or Girl?"
        ),
    )
    return GENDER
 
async def gender(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    user = update.message.from_user
    await update.message.reply_text(
        "Please Enter your email:",
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
    )
 
    return EMAIL
 
async def email(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    if update.message.text != "" and re.match(r'([A-Za-z0-9]+[.-_])*[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,})+', update.message.text):
        await update.message.reply_text(
            "Thanks for your registration",
            reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
        )
    else:
        await update.message.reply_text(
            "Your Email address was wrong!",
            reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
        )
        return GENDER
 
    return ConversationHandler.END
 
async def cancel(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    await update.message.reply_text(
        "Bye! I hope we can talk again some day.", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    )
    return ConversationHandler.END
 
def main() -> None:
    application = Application.builder().token("***************").build()
 
    # Add conversation handler with the states GENDER, PHOTO, LOCATION and BIO
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler("start", start)],
        states={
            GENDER: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, gender)],
            EMAIL: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, email)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler("cancel", cancel)],
    )
 
    application.add_handler(conv_handler)
 
    # Run the bot until the user presses Ctrl-C
    application.run_polling()
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want show to user your Email address was wrong! then Please Enter your email: actually, I want to rerun gender method without waiting user input something or trigger ConversationHandler inside the method

I need something like that for another where. Suppose I want to control the user's state from the database and save steps in the database, so I need to go up and down in conversation, and all thing happens in one method. see this structure

```
async def register(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:

if user.user_status == 'start':

    if user.step == 0:
        //Show Accpet rules
        // if it accepet
            //go to step 1
    elif user.step == 1:
        //get name and family
        //goes to step 2
    elif user.step == 2:
        // check name and family
            // if it was correct
                // save in DB
                // get mobile number
            // if it was not correct
                // show error message 
                // back to step 1 and ask again name and family
    elif user.step == 3:
        // check mobile number 
            // if it was correct
                    // save in DB
                    //get email
            // if it was not correct
                    //show error message 
                    // back to step 2 and ask again mobile number
        // get email
        ....
    elif user.step == 4:
        ...
    elif user.step == 5:

        await update.message.reply_text(
                "you successfull register",
                reply_markup=await _reply_keyboard('GoHome'),parse_mode='HTML'
        )

return Register
```

---

**Update:**

I make a real example to show my mind and my problem. user should enter something until ConversationHandler trigger and it's a big problem try this code:

```
import re

from telegram import __version__ as TG_VER

try:
    from telegram import __version_info__
except ImportError:
    __version_info__ = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

if __version_info__ < (20, 0, 0, "alpha", 1):
    raise RuntimeError(
        f"This example is not compatible with your current PTB version {TG_VER}. To view the "
        f"{TG_VER} version of this example, "
        f"visit https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v{TG_VER}/examples.html"
    )
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, Update
from telegram.ext import (
    Application,
    CommandHandler,
    ContextTypes,
    ConversationHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    filters,
)
step = 0
prev_step = 0
START,RULES,STEPS = range(3)

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    reply_keyboard = [["Yes", "No"]]
    await update.message.reply_text(
        "Hi! My name is Professor Bot. I will hold a conversation with you. "
        "Are you accept rules?",
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
            reply_keyboard, one_time_keyboard=True, input_field_placeholder="Yes or No?"
        ),
    )
    return STEPS

async def steps(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    global step
    global prev_step

    if step == 0:
        print(step,prev_step)
        if update.message.text == "Yes" or prev_step == 1:
            step=1
            prev_step=0
            await update.message.reply_text(
                "Please enter your email address:",
                reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
            )
        else:
            await update.message.reply_text(
                "You should accept rules to continue!",
                reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
            )
            return START

    elif step == 1:
        prev_step = 1
        if update.message.text != "" and re.match(r'([A-Za-z0-9]+[.-_])*[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,})+', update.message.text):
            await update.message.reply_text(
                "Please enter your name:",
                reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
            )
            step = 2
        else:
            step = 0
            await update.message.reply_text(
                "Your Email address was wrong!",
                reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
            )

    return STEPS

async def cancel(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    await update.message.reply_text(
        "Bye! I hope we can talk again some day.", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    )
    return ConversationHandler.END

def main() -> None:
    application = Application.builder().token("*****").build()

    # Add conversation handler with the states GENDER, PHOTO, LOCATION and BIO
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler("start", start)],
        states={
            START: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, start)],
            RULES: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, steps)],
            STEPS: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, steps)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler("cancel", cancel)],
    )

    application.add_handler(conv_handler)

    # Run the bot until the user presses Ctrl-C
    application.run_polling()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way I don't it is the correct way or is standard, but it works:

```
import re

from telegram import __version__ as TG_VER

try:
    from telegram import __version_info__
except ImportError:
    __version_info__ = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

if __version_info__ < (20, 0, 0, "alpha", 1):
    raise RuntimeError(
        f"This example is not compatible with your current PTB version {TG_VER}. To view the "
        f"{TG_VER} version of this example, "
        f"visit https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v{TG_VER}/examples.html"
    )
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, Update
from telegram.ext import (
    Application,
    CommandHandler,
    ContextTypes,
    ConversationHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    filters,
)
step = 0
prev_step = 0
START,RULES,STEPS = range(3)

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    reply_keyboard = [["Yes", "No"]]
    print("(start) Hi! My name is Professor Bot. I will hold a conversation with you....")
    await update.message.reply_text(
        "Hi! My name is Professor Bot. I will hold a conversation with you. "
        "Are you accept rules?",
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
            reply_keyboard, one_time_keyboard=True, input_field_placeholder="Yes or No?"
        ),
    )
    print("(start) return STEPS")
    return STEPS

async def steps(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    global step
    global prev_step

    print(f"(steps) BEGIN -- Step:{step}",f"PreStep:{prev_step}")
    if step == 0:
        print(update.message.text)
        if update.message.text == "Yes" or prev_step == 1:
            step=1
            prev_step=0
            print("Please enter your First email address:")
            await update.message.reply_text(
                "Please enter your First email address:",
                reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
            )
        else:
            print("You should accept rules to continue!")
            await update.message.reply_text(
                "You should accept rules to continue!",
                reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
            )
            await start(update,context)

    elif step == 1:
        print(update.message.text)
        if update.message.text != "" and re.match(r'([A-Za-z0-9]+[.-_])*[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,})+', update.message.text) or prev_step == 2:
            print("Please enter your Second email:")
            await update.message.reply_text(
                "Please enter your Second email:",
                reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
            )
            step = 2
            prev_step = 1
        else:
            prev_step = 1
            step = 0
            print("Your First Email address was wrong!")
            await update.message.reply_text(
                "Your First Email address was wrong!",
                reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
            )
            await steps(update,context)

    elif step == 2:
        print(update.message.text)
        if update.message.text != "" and re.match(r'([A-Za-z0-9]+[.-_])*[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,})+', update.message.text):

            print("Please enter your Third Email:")
            await update.message.reply_text(
                "Please enter your Third Email:",
                reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
            )
            step = 3
            prev_step = 2
        else:
            step = 1
            prev_step = 2
            print("Your Second Email address was wrong!")
            await update.message.reply_text(
                "Your Second Email address was wrong!",
                reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
            )
            await steps(update,context)


    print(f"(steps) END -- GoStep:{step}",f"PreStep:{prev_step}","### return STEPS")
    print("-------------------------------------------------\n")
    return STEPS

async def cancel(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    await update.message.reply_text(
        "Bye! I hope we can talk again some day.", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    )
    return ConversationHandler.END

def main() -> None:
    application = Application.builder().token("*****").build()

    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler("start", start)],
        states={
            START: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, start)],
            RULES: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, steps)],
            STEPS: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, steps)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler("cancel", cancel)],
    )

    application.add_handler(conv_handler)

    # Run the bot until the user presses Ctrl-C
    application.run_polling()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `email` function in the *if* clause when the user didn't provide a valid email address. I would suggest

> Your email address was wrong! Please write it again

With this you can return to the same state in which you were: `return EMAIL` to enter the function again.

In case of a successful answer, `return ConversationHandler.END`